# Calling a function of UIViewController from a child UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have a `UIViewcontroller` on which I have added a `UIView` as a subview and then added another `UIView` as another subview over the first view.

Now I want to call a method in the `UIViewController` from the last `UIView`. All of these views are custom views and have been created as different classes.

What would be the best way to call this topmost view from the child of the child?

Comment: Hi @pankaj are you navigating your uiviewcontroller to another view or it is on same uiviewcontroller ?

Comment: Why are you calling a controller method from a UIView subclass?

Comment: i can not get what you want exactly, if i am not wrong then its simple define your method in yourMainViewController such like -(void)Method; and import yourMainViewController.h in your subView.m file and just create object of yourMainViewController and call this method by object such like yourMainViewController *obj = [[yourMainViewController alloc] init];  and [obj Method];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a view as a UIViewController's subview. I believe you added it as a subview of the controller's view. I do not understand what you mean to ask in the question. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
I assume you want to call a method in the UIViewController on some user interaction. If this view (the child of child)is a button, you could simply do this:

```
[button addTarget:nil action:@selector(methodToCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

A nil target will result in the method methodToCall in the UIViewController to be called.
If you don't see a call there, make sure the view hierarchy (all predecessor views in it) is user interaction enabled.

A better approach (If you haven't subclassed UIButton) would be to create a protocol for your custom views, specify a tap gesture recognizer, specify a delegate and send call a method in the delegate whenever you receive a tap.

Comment: Though this will work, it encourages the wrong type of relationship between the view and the controller. The controller should control the view. It should specify what interaction is possible and how it is handled. The view shouldn't have the knowledge about what method to call.

Comment: Hmmm, You sound correct. I wonder why apple made it so that if the target is nil, the selector will be sent to the viewController, that only seems to encourage this behavior. Also, defining a protocol for small things seems overkill, a simple deviation from the guidelines doesn't hurt anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a view controller is that it's in control of the view. You shouldn't be adding knowledge to the view which requires it to know to pass information to the controller. The view should either have `UIControl`s on it and the controller sets the appropriate target and action or the controller should add gestures to the view and, again, specify appropriate target and action.

Answer (score 0):

I can not get what you want exactly..if you want simple topmost view then you set tag of this view when you call addsubview .and every time increment tag when add subview and decrement tag when remove subview.then you easily get topmost view with help of current tag.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

In `TopView.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) YourViewController *ViewController_object;
```

In `TopView.h`

```
-(void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
    ViewController_object=nil;
}

-(void)your_method {
   [ViewController_object method_from_VC];
}
```

hope it will helps you...